# How to create a hard straight edge while keeping this sphere's shape?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I am trying to create an opening on this sphere which I created by subdividing a cube 3 times. I want the edge of the upper part of the opening not to be curved as shown in the picture so I added a proximity loop. But this messes with the overall shape of the sphere. In the second sphere I moved the edge loop a bit but the problem is still there. How should I do this? If possible only with quads and without the crease tool. This is how the second sphere looks like:

[image: awfaw]

Comment: use sharp edges

Comment: Inset the faces first then extrude them inside?

Comment: @Chebhou Do you mean use sharp edges in order to split them? I want them to look smooth.

Comment: choose the edge and increase the "crease" in the right panel, so the subsurf modifier don't smooth them out

Comment: i would edge slide the offending vertex to the middle and then use normal subsrfs.

Comment: i can't see, would that screw up the geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off by adding a cube, giving it a subserf with a level of three, and applying it.
[image]

Then tab into edit mode, and use the space bar to search for the "to sphere" operation. Use this operation, press 1, and press enter. This takes our cube which was almost spherical, but not quite, and turned it into a perfect sphere.

Then select the middle 16 faces, and inset them a little bit.
[image]

Then extrude those faces back, and scale them along the Y axis to 0 to straighten them out.
[image]

Then add a subserf modifer and move the edges closest to the outside of the hole, out to sharpen up the edge, and then add some edge loops around hole to create some sharper edges.
[image]

Then tab out of edit mode, and admire your finished result!
[image]

Comment: The problem is that inseting first doesnt make the upper edge straight as shown in the picture. That part was fine with the two extra loops inside the opening.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that detail, I'm working on it right now.

Comment: Hows this? http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35756 All I did was use one more level on the subserf on the first round (the one that's applied) and then I just moved around some edges with G+G. There's a small amount of distortion around the edges, but it seems okay to me. If it works for you, I'll update my answer.

Comment: This looks much better indeed. I guess with such curvy shapes you can only work with whatever loops the object already so you have to include the creasing loops in the initial extrusion. Very useful tip, thanks. :)